# What is the meaning of irreducible manifolds

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

According to Wikipedia,

> An **irreducible $n$-manifold**, is one in which any embedded $(n − 1)$-sphere bounds an embedded $n$-ball.

What I understand from this definition is,

> if $\Bbb S^{n-1}$ is a embedded submanifold of $M$ then there is a $n$-ball such that $\partial B_n=\Bbb S^{n-1}$.

is this correct? I don't know why I think this happen always. i.e. such $B_n$ exists always. Is there any $2$-dimensional example of irreducible $2$-manifold for better understanding?

Comment: It might be more illuminating to see a *non*-example. For instance, the punctured plane is *not* irreducible. Can you see why?

Comment: OMG, such a simple example. Thank you @Wojowu.

Comment: As for an example, Jordan-Schoenflies theorem essentially says that $\mathbb R^n$ is irreducible for all $n$.

Comment: @Wojowu, your example is reducible. can you explain, reducible to what?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you mean with being reducible to something?

Comment: The meaning of reducible is reduce to something. isn't? so why geometers call it reducible and irreducible?

Comment: @Wojowu, my question is so unclear?

Comment: It's unclear to me. I don't know the origin of this terminology, so I have no idea if (ir)reducibility refers to reductions of any kind

Comment: Follow-up question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3432171/does-the-meaning-of-irreducible-manifold-is-not-reducible-to-other-manifold

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the sake of providing this with an answer, there are various counter examples. The punctured plane is one, as Wojowu says in the comments.

We also have $\mathbb{R}^3 \backslash \{0\}$, and other similar cases. $T^2$ is another good example for a $2$-dimensional case.

Comment: these are not irreducible, so they are reducible. my another question is reducible to what?

Comment: I believe you would "reduce" by expressing your manifold as a connected sum of irreducible manifolds.

Comment: so in case torus or punched plan, these reduce to?