# Does the meaning of "irreducible manifold" is "not reducible to other manifold"?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

This question is a follow up of [my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3299378/272127).

> What does "irreducible manifold" mean?
>
> My understanding of "irreducible manifold" is "not reducible (homotopic or deformation or homeomorph or being prime manifold or something like these) to other manifold".
>
> What is the origin of this terminology?

Comment: Do you want to know the actual history of using "reducible" and "irreducible" in this context, or do you want to know why the two words are sensible names for these concepts?

Comment: second one. it would be very nice if you give some reference for first one.

Comment: Now posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/347160/does-the-meaning-of-irreducible-manifold-is-not-reducible-to-other-manifold

Answer (score 0):

The [connected sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_sum) along $S^3$ turns the class of all compact, connected, boundaryless, smooth oriented manifolds of dimension $3$ [into a monoid](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/93512/monoid-structure-of-oriented-manifolds-with-connect-sum). Irreducible manifolds are [irreducible elements](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/irreducible+element#:%7E:text=1.-,Definition,in%20the%20list%20is%20invertible.) of this monoid. In other words "irreducible" refers to the fact that it cannot be obtained as the connected sum of non-trivial manifolds (trivial being the $3$-sphere).

Apparently it is not known if the situation is the same for higher dimension, but as a justification of the origin of the term "irreducible" in this context might be a satisfying answer

Comment: Did you proofread before posting?

Comment: A little care should be used regarding the kind of category we are considering (eg. homotopic, differentiable, ..) but i think as a justification it make sense. At least in dimension three it should work well

Comment: @MoisheKohanonstrike thanks for gently pointing out that I stated something way to strong, i corrected it into something more reasonable

Comment: @Dinisaur: thanks for your post. see [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/394522/90655) that your post is part of that.